# AngularJs open external links in an cordova app

Tags: angularjs, cordova-plugins, angularjs-filter, ngsanitize

using ng-bind-html in cordova app trying to open external link .

1. I have installed InAppBrowser plugin[image]
2. Then i have followed the exact steps from the following 
   https://gist.github.com/rewonc/e53ad3a9d6ca704d402e
3. The code with the filter gets executed and the link in it gets changed that is href to window.open code.

But when i click on the link nothing happens.

Anything else i am missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the html that used the ng-bind-html

```
<div class="card" ng-if="extendedDescription">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                Ext Description
            </div>
            <label class="item item-text-wrap">
                <span ng-bind-html="extendedDescription">
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

The span element was wrapped inside the label element because of which none of the events were fired changed

> `the <label to only contain <span`